# Unable to get Nvidia drivers to work on GeForce GT755M (Optimus)

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I am trying to get Ubuntu 13.10 running on a Lenovo Y510p with a GeForce GT755M graphics card. I have followed countless tutorials on the web, all to no avail. The methods I have tried include:

1) installing latest Nvidia drivers from their website (3.31)
2) installing latest Nvidia drivers from PPAs (3.31, 3.19-updates)
3) installing `nvidia-current` (3.04)
4) setting up `bumblebee` with Nvidia drivers  (3.31, 3.19-updates, 3.04)

and various combinations of these. The drivers don't work when I install them (they are not being used), and when I enable them with `jockey-text`, Unity doesn't load at all: it displays a black screen after login (3.31) or `lightdm` restarts after entering the user password (3.19-updates).

I have tried installing Linux Mint as well, and Cinnamon does not load with the Nvidia drivers (it reports a crash and enters fallback mode).

The system works without the drivers, running on the integrated Intel card, but I would prefer to get the Nvidia card set up properly. Additionally, when the system starts to boot, the screen brightness always gets set to 0 and I need to manually turn it up.

I would appreciate any help or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all avaliable drivers for nvidia and the best I've found are the ones from X-edgers ppa:

First, be sure you remove all drivers you've previously installed:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia*
```

Then, add this ppa and install the drivers from it:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia nvidia-331 nvidia-settings-331
```